# External CSS !important overriding inline !important

Tags: html, css, media-queries, squarespace

I have a *inline* CSS rule added to removing padding-top & padding-bottom from a div that is added by a external stylesheet CSS rule I cannot modify that uses !important. 
Below are the two divs I am trying to modify.

```
<div class="class1 class2 class3 class4">
<div class="class1 class5 class6">
```

I declared the following;

```
  .class2 {
    padding: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
  }
  .class5 {
    padding: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
    padding-top: 0 !important;
  }
```

But the external CSS file is loading this rule, overriding my inline rule;

```
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .parent1 .parent2 .class1:first-child {
        padding-top: 17px !important;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
    .parent 1 .parent2 .class1:last-child {
        padding-bottom: 17px !important;
    }
}
```

Why would this override my inline CSS rule? Isn't any inline rule (especially with !important) supposed to override all external CSS (even with !important)? From my understanding of specificity, is that any inline style has two orders of magnitude more specificity

(1, 1, 0, 1, 0)

than the multi-parent with psuedo selector

(1, 0, 0, 4, 0).

[See here for documentation.](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors-3/#specificity) [Also here.](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS22/cascade.html#specificity) [And certainly here.](https://specifishity.com/)

Edit: It appears my understanding of origin-specificity values was flawed as pointed out by @myf. Inline `<style>[css rules]</style>` have the same original specificity value as `<link>` css files. Therefore in my original CSS rule I would have had a lower specificity than Squarespace's. Only  have the higher origin-specificity value. Please read @myf 's response, it's very helpful.

Comment: Check out [MDN: CSS Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) for more on why this happens. The external CSS is more specific, which is why it took priority.

Comment: @SunnyPatel I did read the MDN page for specificity, that was one of the first things I went to for help. But, MDN also states any inline CSS should override external CSS even if they both have !important (because with "a, b, c, d, e" external CSS has a b=0 while inline has b=1, and since both share !important and have "a=1" then shouldn't the inline value override?). Please see my calculation of each CSS rule's specificity below.

Comment: In this context, it helps to take the meaning of "inline" as very literal, as in actually on the same line, and as part of an element. Anything else would not be considered "inline" at all (relatively speaking). Also, all else being the same, rules with more specifics tend to always override rules with less specifics. If it works, and your syntax isn't flawed (ie not a fluke) then that's how CSS works. Most people learn this through raw experience, but to each their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have apparently confused *inline style origin* that originates from **physical HTML attribute** (`<el style="[css declarations]">`) with in-page style sheet that has **"author"** level origin specificity and originates either from `<style>[css rules]</style>` or `<link rel="stylesheet" href="[css file url]">`.

Style and link elements in page are origin-wise equal, attribute is more origin-wise specific.

It is not possible to beat `!important` rules from **inline** origin level (attribute) with `!important` rule from **author** level origin.

Comment: Thank you so much!  In this case since I was using <style>[css]</style> instead of <el style="[css]"> it's sharing the same origin-specificity value as <link>. Since I was using author-level rules, then I would have had the same b value in "a,b,c,d,e" as the external stylesheet. I should have been using <el style="[css]"> as that would have had a higher origin-specificity value. My fundamental understanding of how origin specificity worked was flawed.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by using more parent selectors than the one used by Squarespace. I ended up using this;

```
.parent1 .parent2 .parent3 .class {
    padding-top: 0 !important;
    padding-bottom: 0 !important;
}
```

But I am still confused why this would work. Especially because the documentation specifically (get it?) states that inline values hold a "b=1" value in the "a, b, c, d, e" order of specificity while each parent selector only has an additional "d=1" value and !important values have a "a=1" value.

For reference, specificity is

> "!important 1/0 (if using=1, if not=0), inline 1/0 (if inline=1, if not=0), id (total #id usage), class/attrib/psuedo (total .class, [attrib], or :pseudo usage), element (total html body header main nav etc. usage)"

So my original selector (without the multiple parents) would equal

> "1, 1, 0, 1, 0" `(EDIT: I used <style>css</style> NOT <el style="css"> therefore the actual value is "1, 0, 0, 1, 0" because <style> rules have the same specificity value as external <link> stylesheets)`

because I am using !important so "a=1", using inline "b=1" `EDIT: "b=0"`, not using IDs "c=0", using 1 class selector "d=1", not using element selector "e=0"

And the Squarespace selector would equal

> "1, 0, 0, 4, 0,"

because !important "a=1", not inline "b=0", not using IDs "c=0", 4 class/pseudo usages total "d=4", not using element selector "e=0".

Therefore my original selector should have overridden the Squarespace selector.

But instead the new selector which equals

> "1, 1, 0, 4, 0" `EDIT: "1, 0, 0, 4, 0" see above edit`

(see below) is the only one that worked.

Because !important "a=1", inline "b=1", not using IDs "c=0", four total class usages "d=4", not using element selector "e=0"